# Compile errors with Maven but not in Eclipse after upgrade from java 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, eclipse-luna

I am aware that similar questions has been asked in the past, but I couldn't found my answer in it.

I am using Eclipse Luna and upgraded to java 8 (build 0.25).
The JAVA_HOME points to java 8 and also it's part of the Windows Classpath.

After the upgrade, maven compile shows some Ambiguous method calls that didn't show up in java 7.
The problem is that these errors aren't shown in Eclipse and I can't find why.
I removed all jre's in eclipse and removed/added the java 8 jdk, but still no luck.
Also Eclipse is using the java 8 environment for compiler errors/warnings.

With maven I use the "plexus-compiler-javac" compiler, snapshot 2-4. I also tried without the plexus compiler and with version 2.0, but no luck.

Any idea what this could be?

My Pom snippet:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                <!--version>2.0</version-->
                <version>2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <configuration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <fork>false</fork>
            <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
            <meminitial>256m</meminitial>
            <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT version of plexus-compiler ? Please show your pom file.

Comment: I just added the pom.xml snippet.

Comment: did you check project properties in eclipse and ensured that it is using Jdk 1.8 and not jdk 1.7. Check compatibility for source and target configuration as well.

Comment: Yes, I also describe that in the question (I only have one jre, namely java 8).

Answer (score 3):

Try telling maven to use java 8 source level by adding/changing configuration of your compile plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I do, but has no effect.

Comment: Maybe it's related to plexus compiler. Have you tried new configuration, but, without the dependency to plexus compiler?

Comment: Yes, this is noted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

i face this issue with tools.jar not found, so download the latest tools.jar & copy to D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25..\lib\tools.jar, thanks.